# Why Dropdown values not coming using typescript?

Tags: typescript, api, react-hooks, dropdown, react-typescript

Trying to bind data to dropdown, but not binding anything, dropdown displayes NOTHING SELECTED.

```
 function Drop() {
    axios.get('/api/v1/users/')
    .then(function (response) {
      global_num = response.data;
      // console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });

    let lst = [];
    for (let i in global_num) {
      lst.push(global_num[i]['username']);
    }

    
    return (
      <select style={{ width : "300px" , height: "40px", margin:"20px", fontSize:"18px"}} name="res"> 
      {lst?.map((list) => (
      <option value={list}> {list} </option>
      ))}
      </select> 
    );
  }
```

API result where username used for display as a dropdown options

```
Response from API:

[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "hanwat007@gmail.com",

    }
]
```

Comment: because the `get` is asynchronous, your return finishes before the api call completes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React components render synchronously, which means that here your UI is rendered before you receive your HTTP response, and isn't updated when the response arrives later. That means your `for (let i in global_num) { ...` code runs *before* the response arrives.

Instead, your component should:

- Create some state in your component to store the response data, using `useState`
- Start sending the request when your component first renders, with `useEffect`
- When rendered with no state set, show some kind of loading message or spinner
- When the response arrives (in your `then` callback) call `setState` with the response data - this will update the component's state and trigger a re-render
- When the component renders and there is state available, *then* you can use it and show all your list items.